# New column computed from another columns in the declaration - Views - SqlAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, view, sqlalchemy, label

I have this class to create a materialized view in PostgreSQL:

```
class TotalProfit(ExecutionsBase):
    stmt = (
        select(
            [
                TotalRealizedCapital.symbolExchange.label("symbolExchange"),
                TotalRealizedCapital.symbol.label("symbol"),
                TotalRealizedCapital.currency.label("currency"),
                TotalRealizedCapital.totalRealizedCapital.label("totalRealizedCap"),
                OpenPosition.totalUnrealizedCapital.label("totalUnrealizedCap"), #- simplified  
                Dividend.totalDividends.label("totalDividends"), #- simplified
                ("totalRealizedCap" + "totalDividends" + "totalUnrealizedCap").label("total"),
            ]
        )
        .select_from(TotalRealizedCapital)
        .order_by("symbolExchange", "symbol", "currency")
    )

    view = create_materialized_view(
        name="vw_total_profit",
        selectable=stmt,
        metadata=ExecutionsBase.metadata,
        indexes=None,
    )
    __table__ = view
```

I want to add a **total column** which is a **sum of the previous columns**:
total = totalRealizedCap + totalDividends + totalUnrealizedCap

I've searched ways to do that with Computed() and column_property() but it seems it is of no use within a selectable.

**Is there a way to create a new label column computed from the values    of other labeled columns?**

---

**Update:**

It seems there isn't a way to refer to aliases in the same select (database constraint). Some are suggesting the use of **db variables**, others are suggesting the use of **subqueries** and others are suggesting the use of **CTE**.

I'm trying to figure out how translate this possibilities do a select statement to create a view with SqlAlchemy.

Comment: I also have tried a solution with literal_column("totalRealizedCap") but that refers to the column on the original table and not the column of the view being created.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with CTE:**

```
class TotalProfit(ExecutionsBase):
    first_cte = (
        select(
            [
                TotalRealizedCapital.symbolExchange.label("symbolExchange"),
                TotalRealizedCapital.symbol.label("symbol"),
                TotalRealizedCapital.totalRealizedCapital.label("totalRealizedCap"),
                OpenPosition.totalUnrealizedCapital.label(
                    "totalUnrealizedCap"
                ),
                Dividend.totalDividends.label("totalDividends"),
            ]
        )
        .select_from(TotalRealizedCapital)
        .order_by("symbolExchange", "symbol")
        .cte()
    )

    stmt = (
        select(
            [
                TotalRealizedCapital.symbolExchange.label("symbolExchange"),
                TotalRealizedCapital.symbol.label("symbol"),
                first_cte.c.totalRealizedCap,
                first_cte.c.totalUnrealizedCap,
                first_cte.c.totalDividends,
                (
                    first_cte.c.totalRealizedCap
                    + first_cte.c.totalUnrealizedCap
                    + first_cte.c.totalDividends
                ).label("total"),
            ]
        )
        .select_from(TotalRealizedCapital)
        .where(
            (TotalRealizedCapital.symbolExchange == first_cte.c.symbolExchange)
            & (TotalRealizedCapital.symbol == first_cte.c.symbol)
        )
        .order_by("symbolExchange", "symbol")
    )

    view = create_materialized_view(
        name="vw_total_profit",
        selectable=stmt,
        metadata=ExecutionsBase.metadata,
        indexes=None,
    )
    __table__ = view
```